# TextBox Label Control

Tags: c#, textbox, controls, label, new-operator

I am not worried about whether this is in Winforms or WPF.

Is there ANY way at all that I could develop my own user control like the one found in Microsoft Paint, below:

[image]

If you can't see the pic above, it's here: http://img232.imageshack.us/i/txtboxlblctrl.png/
Is there anyway at all I can do something like this in C#?

Thank you

Comment: Neither of your links seem to work

Comment: Thanks. Uh, I know the pic doesnt display on here which is strange, but the linki is working for me. I don't know...

Comment: I'm curious, are you deciding whether to use WPF or WinForms based only on this?

Comment: Correct, I know how to implement all other functionality of my application on either Winforms or WPF. So this is the only thing left I need to do. And once I know whether wpf or winforms would be better for this, then I'll write the app :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure you can. By developing your own Usercontrol you can do nearly anything.
I think the easiest way would be to use a WPF TextBox and alternate it with a template.

This [http://img199.imageshack.us/i/textboxu.png/] is what you get by simply using [http://img163.imageshack.us/i/stipe.png/] as BorderBrush

Comment: And my final followup question: Can TextBox controls be made fully Transparent in WPF?

Comment: Sure, you can change the Visibility property to hide it completely, and you can make the BackgroundBrush transparent for just no background.

Comment: yaaay i'm excited! than you for your answers :) i'll mark as answer when it decides to let me lol

Comment: Hmm, dont know why, but it works after visiting the gallery : http://img199.imageshack.us/gal.php?g=textboxu.png